# Does the Stripe extension process payments for companies based in Spain?

Tags: drupal, stripe

I have a client running Drupal 7.58 and CiviCRM 4.7.19 that I would like to install the Stripe extension for. Stripe assures me that they process payments for merchants based in Spain, but the Civi documentation only says USA CA and UK. Stripe suggested that I check with the extension maintainers to make sure that it will work for merchants based in Spain. Anybody that can give a definitive answer on this one?

Comment: Sorry - can't - but i have Stripe working on an NZ site which may prove the documentation is out of date

Comment: I have Stripe running in France : no problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure but Mollie is a great alternative. It works with the omnipay module of CiviCRM.